# Efficient way to compare a new data with huge existing database

Tags: database, search, neo4j, database-performance, graph-databases

I have a object or data contains id,name,city,pin,email,phone details. I have collected huge data like this. Now i would like to compare a new data with  existing huge data and finally need to see how maximum the data were matching.

Currently i am iterating the exiting data in multiple threads to resolve this and it takes huge time consuming.

*Example:
Existing data ,
id=1,name=A,city=B,pin=1,email=C,phone=1
id=2,name=D,city=F,pin=1,email=G,phone=1

new Data

id=1,name=A,city=B,pin=2,email=C,phone=2

Result;
similar data with maximum match is first row id,name,email are matching*

Is there a optimized enterprise solution for this ?

Comment: Is there a easy way to solve this by Graph data base ? How to get close match ?

Answer (score 0):

We use [Redgate's SQL Compare tool](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/?gclid=CMLFjenz09QCFYa77QodBs8GeQ), which is quite efficient.

Comment: Updated my question with an example